# Boost scoped_lock usage with boost condition variables

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I am trying to use condition variables to implement printing of numbers in sequence from two threads, one printing even numbers and the other printing odd ones.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <condition_variable>
using namespace std;

boost::mutex m;
boost::condition_variable cv_even;
boost::condition_variable cv_odd;
bool even_done = false;
bool odd_done = false;
bool wait_main = true;
void odd_printer(){
  cout<<"Start odd\n";
  int i = 0;
  while(true){
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(m);
    cout<<"Odd acquired lock " << i << endl;
    while(!even_done) cv_odd.wait(lock);
    if(i % 2 == 1){
      cout<<i<<endl;
    }
    i++;
    even_done = false;
    odd_done = true;
    cv_even.notify_one();
  }
}

void even_printer(){
  cout<<"Start even\n";
  int i = 0;
  while(true){
    boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(m);
    cout<<"Even acquired lock " << i << endl;
    while(!odd_done) cv_even.wait(lock);
    if(i % 2 == 0){
      cout<<i<<endl;
    }
    i++;
    odd_done = false;
    even_done = true;
    cv_odd.notify_one();
    cout<<"End scope even\n";
  }
}

int main(){
  boost::thread odd_t{odd_printer};
  boost::thread even_t{even_printer};
  sleep(2);
  odd_done = true;
  cv_even.notify_one();
  odd_t.join();
  even_t.join();
}
```

The output I get before the `sleep(2)` statement finishes is:

```
Start even
Even acquired lock 0
Start odd
Odd acquired lock 0
```

How can both the threads acquire the lock on mutex m. In other words the statement `boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(m);` goes through in both the threads. Shouldn't one of them wait for the other one to release the lock on mutex m first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way this works is that `cv.wait(lock)` unlocks the lock and locks again before returning.  That's how the other threads can lock and continue.  That is the reason why the lock must be passed to the wait-function.

Ideally, the main should also lock before accessing the shared flags.